# session with no cookies

Tags: asp.net

I ran into a situation that I brought onto myself by disabling cookies: session state wasn't working as expected. How do you check to see that the user has cookies enabled in an http module?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a cookie and then redirect them to a page inside the same site. If you don't get a cookie back, then they don't have cookies enabled. You can track them through this adventure by embedding a code in the URL or submitting a form.

Assuming you've rigged the page to set a cookie already, you can also use JavaScript to retrieve a "did you send a cookie" page. Then you can look at what you got back to see if the browser returned the cookie you sent it.

Comment: Then just make a web page that checks if a cookie is set. Retrieve that URL and inspect the results. If you like XML, it can just return `<COOKIE>YES</COOKIE>` or `<COOKIE>NO</COOKIE>`. Whatever you like. If you've already set a cookie, retrieving any page (in the cookie's scope) will tell you.

Comment: @frenchie You probably need to use the javascript method then.

Comment: I'm looking to use an http module that'll check  for the cookie. Is there a way to do it like that?

Answer (score 1):

If you have cookies disabled on your browser , then you can create a hidden field in your html page which will store your cookie value.

```
< input type='hidden' name='sessionid' >
```

Retrieve this value when you move to next page .